# Tweepy Python library "media_ids parameter is invalid" and "Tweet must not have more than 4 mediaIds" when submitting status update. Codes 44 and 324

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have some pretty simple code for uploading images to Twitter via the Tweepy library and then posting a status update using the returned media ids. I've seen a lot of questions on this topic here but none that have solved my problem. Code is as follows.

```
import tweepy
from configparser import SafeConfigParser

config = SafeConfigParser()
config.read('/var/www/config.ini')

CONSUMER_KEY = config.get('twitter', 'CONSUMER_KEY')
CONSUMER_SECRET = config.get('twitter', 'CONSUMER_SECRET')
ACCESS_KEY = config.get('twitter', 'ACCESS_KEY')
ACCESS_SECRET = config.get('twitter', 'ACCESS_SECRET')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

file = open('/var/www/photo1.jpeg', 'rb')
r1 = api.media_upload(filename='/var/www/photo1.jpeg', file=file)
print(r1)
print(r1.media_id_string)
file = open('/var/www/photo2.jpeg', 'rb')
r2 = api.media_upload(filename='/var/www/photo2.jpeg', file=file)
print(r2)
print(r2.media_id_string)
media_ids = r1.media_id_string + ', ' + r2.media_id_string
print(media_ids)
api.update_status(media_ids=media_ids, status="Test Tweet")
```

When executing this script I get the following error at the last line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 26, in <module>
    api.update_status(media_ids=media_ids, status="Test Tweet")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 194, in update_status
    )(post_data=post_data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'media_ids parameter is invalid.', 'code': 44}]
```

The 2 media upload requests return the following objects:

```
Media(media_id=728190961679929344, size=879715, expires_after_secs=86400,
media_id_string='728190961679929344', _api=<tweepy.api.API object at
0x7ffaf4d8fda0>, image={'h': 4000, 'w': 5000, 'image_type': 'image/jpeg'})
```

and

```
Media(media_id=728190987122532353, size=17489, expires_after_secs=86400,
media_id_string='728190987122532353', _api=<tweepy.api.API object at
0x7ffaf4d8fda0>, image={'h': 369, 'w': 640, 'image_type': 'image/jpeg'})
```

from which I extract the media ids of `728190961679929344` and `728190987122532353` as strings through the media_id_string variable and combine them into a single string separated by commas i.e. `728190961679929344, 728190987122532353`. I've tried with and without the space, in single and double quotations, singularly quoted and quoting the entire string but nothing works.

If instead I try just update with a single image id as in the following

```
import tweepy
from configparser import SafeConfigParser

config = SafeConfigParser()
config.read('/var/www/config.ini')

CONSUMER_KEY = config.get('twitter', 'CONSUMER_KEY')
CONSUMER_SECRET = config.get('twitter', 'CONSUMER_SECRET')
ACCESS_KEY = config.get('twitter', 'ACCESS_KEY')
ACCESS_SECRET = config.get('twitter', 'ACCESS_SECRET')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

file = open('/var/www/photo1.jpeg', 'rb')
r1 = api.media_upload(filename='/var/www/photo1.jpeg', file=file)
print(r1)
print(r1.media_id_string)
file = open('/var/www/photo2.jpeg', 'rb')
r2 = api.media_upload(filename='/var/www/photo2.jpeg', file=file)
print(r2)
print(r2.media_id_string)
media_ids = r1.media_id_string + ', ' + r2.media_id_string
print(media_ids)
api.update_status(media_ids=r1.media_id_string, status="Test Tweet")
```

I get the following error again at the last line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 26, in <module>
    api.update_status(media_ids=r1.media_id_string, status="Test Tweet")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 194, in update_status
    )(post_data=post_data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Tweet must not have more than 4 mediaIds.', 'code': 324}]
```

Clearly I only have 1 media id, so the error makes no sense. I assume I'm formatting the request incorrectly but I've tried a range of different formats and none seem to work.

Any ideas as I'm out??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the media_ids was not formatted as a string but instead a list of strings, this differs from the Twitter API documentation and thus Tweepy must format the request from the list before wrapping. Here is my code firstly for multiple images:

```
import tweepy
from configparser import SafeConfigParser

config = SafeConfigParser()
config.read('/var/www/config.ini')

CONSUMER_KEY = config.get('twitter', 'CONSUMER_KEY')
CONSUMER_SECRET = config.get('twitter', 'CONSUMER_SECRET')
ACCESS_KEY = config.get('twitter', 'ACCESS_KEY')
ACCESS_SECRET = config.get('twitter', 'ACCESS_SECRET')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

file = open('/var/www/photo1.jpeg', 'rb')
r1 = api.media_upload(filename='/var/www/photo1.jpeg', file=file)
print(r1)
print(r1.media_id_string)
file = open('/var/www/photo2.jpeg', 'rb')
r2 = api.media_upload(filename='/var/www/photo2.jpeg', file=file)
print(r2)
print(r2.media_id_string)
media_ids = [r1.media_id_string, r2.media_id_string]
print(media_ids)
api.update_status(media_ids=media_ids, status="Test Tweet")
```

and then for a single image:

```
import tweepy
from configparser import SafeConfigParser

config = SafeConfigParser()
config.read('/var/www/config.ini')

CONSUMER_KEY = config.get('twitter', 'CONSUMER_KEY')
CONSUMER_SECRET = config.get('twitter', 'CONSUMER_SECRET')
ACCESS_KEY = config.get('twitter', 'ACCESS_KEY')
ACCESS_SECRET = config.get('twitter', 'ACCESS_SECRET')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

file = open('/var/www/photo1.jpeg', 'rb')
r1 = api.media_upload(filename='/var/www/photo1.jpeg', file=file)
print(r1)
print(r1.media_id_string)
file = open('/var/www/photo2.jpeg', 'rb')
r2 = api.media_upload(filename='/var/www/photo2.jpeg', file=file)
print(r2)
print(r2.media_id_string)
media_ids = [r1.media_id_string_ids]
print(media_ids)
api.update_status(media_ids=media_ids, status="Test Tweet")
```